# Why await sometimes create new thread but sometimes not?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rst = DownloadPage("http://www.baidu.com");
        //var rst2=GetString();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<string> DownloadPage(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            PringMsgWithThreadId("Before await");
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false);
            var content= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            PringMsgWithThreadId(content.Substring(0, 10));
            PringMsgWithThreadId("After await");
            return content;
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetString()
    {
        PringMsgWithThreadId("Before await");
        var result = await GetStringAsync();

        PringMsgWithThreadId(result);
        PringMsgWithThreadId("After await");
        return result;
    }

    private static Task<string> GetStringAsync()
    {
        var task = new Task<string>(() =>
          {
              Thread.Sleep(1000 * 2);
              return "string after sleep two seconds";
          });
        task.RunSynchronously();
        return task;
    }

    private static void PringMsgWithThreadId(string tag)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{tag}(ThreadId:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})");
    }
}
```

output when run DownloadPage() method output:

[image]

output when run GetString() method

[image]

My question:

1.when call DownloadPage(),why code after await executed in the thread(ThreadID:15) other than main thread(ThreadId:10).

2.when call GetString(),why code after await executed in the same thread(both threadId is 10)。

Comment: In what language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`await` *never* creates a new thread.

As explained on my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), `await` will first examine its argument (the task). If it has already completed, then it continues executing synchronously. Otherwise, it "pauses" the method and registers a callback with its argument (i.e., places a continuation on the task).

Later, when the task completes, the continuation will run. Since you're in a Console app without a `SynchronizationContext`/`TaskScheduler`, that continuation will run on a thread pool thread.

So, the answer to your first question is that the main thread is busy (blocked in `Console.ReadKey`), and also the main thread in a Console app isn't a thread pool thread anyway. The answer to your second question is because the task in `GetStringAsync` is run *synchronously* and is already complete by the time it returns, and this causes the `await` in `GetString` to continue (synchronously).

On a side note, you should never, ever, use the task constructor. If you want to return an already-completed task, use `Task.FromResult`. If you want to execute some work on a background thread, use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and article make me undersatnd async/await deeply.